# get position of instance of the same type in the stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

hi i'd like to count and get position of instance of the same type in the stage.
i have tried:

```
var target; 
for(var item in _root){     
if(_root[item] instanceof MovieClip ||   _root[item] instanceof TextField){         
target = _root[item];         
trace("ITEM: "+target);         
trace("X: "+target._x);         
trace("Y: "+target._y);         
trace("----------------");     } }
```

but it says access to property _root undefined, and instanceof deprecated
how can i make it?
thanks

Comment: Use `stage` instead of `_root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in as3 you can loop through all children of your stage (or parent movieclip):

```
for (var i : int = 0;i < stage.numChildren;i++) 
{
    var displayObject : DisplayObject = stage.getChildAt(i);
    if(displayObject is TextField || displayObject is MovieClip)
    {
        trace("ITEM: " + displayObject);         
        trace("X: " + displayObject.x);         
        trace("Y: " + displayObject.y);         
        trace("----------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use: stage instead of _root it is not entering the loop

Comment: *_root* (underscore) is AS2, *stage* (no capital *S*) is AS3. the *stage* object doesn't exist in AS2 and the AS2 compiler doesn't throw any error when it finds an unknown / invalid type that's why you don't see anything. which version of AS do you use 2 or 3?

Comment: i have used AS3, and wrote the code suggested by bjornson. but: the objec i have drawn on the screen isn't recognized, if i make some code where i write addChild(new Ball()) then it recognize the object. if i draw into the screen other object, they seem not recognized as they not were on the stage

Comment: stage.getChildByName gets what i have in the stage